# Adding styles to Azure Bot

Tags: azure, styles, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have created a bot for azure for a web page, but I need to add styles and make it more presentable. How can I add styles? Attached photos of more or less what I need 
I need this:

[image: I need this],

This is my bot:
[image: my code bot i azure]

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the channel you re using to publish your bot. However, channels like Skype, Facebook Messenger or Slack don't allow you to do that. They got their own styling and you cant customize it.

The best approach for you, if you really need to customize the styling is exposing your bot through Direct Line Api and then build your own UI (for instance, your Web page).

Or you can take a look at the Rich Cards Bot Framework provides:

https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/attachments.html

https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node/cards-RichCards

Answer (score 0):

The control on the right is the [BotFramework-WebChat](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat).  It is open source, so you can download it, modify the css and host it yourself.

https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.css

https://unpkg.com/botframework-webchat/botchat.js

Rich cards are another option (as suggested by Gabriel in his answer)

Edit: http://adaptivecards.io/ were released last week, and are exactly what you're looking for!